# send data to service in angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, observable, behaviorsubject

There are 4 multiselect dropdown and on click event I save the data array of object in same component
now I have to send this data to show it in other component.

For this I am using service.
but each time, I send data it will over write the old, I am looking for solution to add the data in new array.

**component**

```
  query = [
    {
      a: [],
      b: [],
      c: [],
      d: []
    }
  ];
```

I need to add new data into query array. can we do with `Behaviorsubject`.

can anybody help me with this.

Comment: it would be great if can give more detail, like explain each step with proper example, otherwise it would be difficult to figure out the exact  prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
addValue(v) {
 const curr = this.yourBehaviorSubject.value;

 this.yourBehaviorSubject.next({ a: [...curr.a, v.a], b: [...curr.b, v.b], c: [...curr.c, v.c], d: [...curr.d, v.d]});
}
```